# How to set which tab is active depending on which button was clicked to come to page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button "Find Game" and a nav link "Login" on homepage. Both links go to the same page "player.html" but when "Find Games" is selected, I want that tab to be the active tab but when "login" is selected, I want the active tab to be "Profile".

At the moment, "Find Games" tab is the active tab when page is opened. How can I do this?

html

```
<ul class="navigation">
            <li id="myProfile-tab" class="nav-myTabs">
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#information"><img id="profile-colour" class="center-block" src="images/david_profilepic.png" alt="Player icon" width="40" height="40"><br>My Profile
                </a>            
            </li>
            <li id="findGames-tab" class="active nav-myTabs">
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#find-games">
                    <img class="center-block" src="images/pitch.png" alt="Pitch icon" width="30" height="30"><br>Find Games
                </a>
            </li>                   
            <li id="myBenches-tab" class="nav-myTabs">
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#my-benches">
                    <img id="bench-colour" class="center-block" src="images/white_bench.png" alt="Black bench" width="30" height="12"><br>My Benches</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

I have added the following javascript to homepage "login"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click", profileTab);
</script>
```

and this to my javascript file:

```
$(function profileTab() {
      $('findGames-tab').removeClass('active');
      $('myProfile-tab').addClass('active');
    }
)
```

Comment: maybe you'll need `php` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a click event handler to anchor element and toggle the active class on its closest 'li' element:

```
$(".navigation a[data-toggle='tab']").click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active')
  });
```

*NOTE: you can improve the performance of code by specifying id's to anchors as attribute based search is not that much proficient.*

Comment: Thanks Vijay. I'm only starting javascript and we've barely scratched the surface so I'm not too sure how to use this

Comment: Remove your existing javascript code anand use the one i provided.  It will bind the click event to anchor tags and toggle the classes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the query string to store which tab you want open by default, and have each link use a different value.

such as:

```
<a href="/player.html?openTab=findGames">Find Games</a>
<a href="/player.html?openTab=myProfile">Login</a>
```

and then use something like this javascript snippet to pull the value:

```
(function (jQuery) {
    jQuery.QueryString = (function(a) {
        if (a == "") return {};
        var b = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            var p = a[i].split('=');
            if (p.length != 2) continue;
            b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        return b;
    })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));
})(jQuery);
```

Like so:

```
var tab = jQuery.QueryString['openTab']
var tabHref = jQuery('#' + tab + '-tab').attr('href');
jQuery('#tabs').tabs('select', tabHref);
```

Another option utilizing urls is to use the location.hash in a similar manner.

Comment: Thanks Jarga. I'm only starting javascript and we've barely scratched the surface so this is way over my head. Is it possible to show with my id "myProfile-tab"?

Comment: Thats what this will do.  Though this is geared towards jQuery tabs, if you have your own tabs then the last two line of the last snippet will be different. probably `$('.nav-myTabs').removeClass('active');` and `$('#' + tab + '-tab').addClass('active');`